# When an exception is thrown out of a (create/copy/move) constructor when throwing a previous exception, why is not std::terminate() called?

Tags: c++, exception

When an exception is thrown out of a (create/copy/move) constructor when throwing a previous exception, why is not `std::terminate()` called? Isn’t it disruption of handling the previous exception before the previous exception is caught, which must cause `std::terminate()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, an exception is considered to be uncaught only after completing the initialization of the exception object (and until completing the activation of a handler for the exception).
If an exception is rethrown, it is considered to be uncaught from the point of rethrown.